# Share in app purchase between Mac and iOS apps

Tags: ios, macos, in-app-purchase

i am developing an app for Mac and iOS, for which I'd like to offer an IAP to unlock full functionality. Ideally, the customer would be able to restore that non consumable purchase on their other iOS devices as well as their Mac.

While the IAP documentation makes clear that non consumable purchases can be made on Mac and iOS, it has nothing to say about whether a single purchase on one platform can be used on the other. Can anyone provide an answer to this question?

Answer (score 1):

To my understanding Mac and iOS apps are considered separate apps and I have not seen anything in iTunes connect that would link in app purchases on one with another. Just like you can't purchase one then automatically get the other for free. With that being said I can see too possible solutions.

First solution would be to use a server to also store what has been purchased. Provide some sort of login and then they can download/unlock what has been purchased no matter what the platform because it would be tide to an account.

If a third party server is not the solution. I would consider some sort of file sharing or syncing between the mac and ios app. [MultipeerConnectivity](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MultipeerConnectivity/Reference/MultipeerConnectivityFramework/index.html) might be an option where a device that "has" purchased can sync with a device that has not. This would require both the Mac and the iOS device to be near and there are some limitations on what devices can do this, but might also be an option.

Hopefully some of that helps.